# Conceptually understanding specificity

Tags: biostatistics, population

If highly specific tests are usually used for confirmatory testing (and highly sensitive tests for screening), it seems that True Positive would be the most important factor for highly specific tests. However, it is not a factor in its equation TN/(TN+FP). I understand wanting the least FP for highly specific tests, but the relation to TN instead of TP does not make sense to me.

I am hoping someone can say something that makes it click.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to think about this from the perspective of the costs of *incorrect* classifications. See the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Definition), as there is more than one formula for sensitivity and specificity.

Sensitivity (aka recall, true positive rate, ...) is equivalent to `1-FNR`, where `FNR` is the false negative rate. High sensitivity thus means that you don't make many false negative classifications. That's what you might want for screening, where there is a high cost of *missing a true positive*.

Specificity (aka selectivity or true negative rate) is equivalent to `1-FPR`, where `FPR` is the false positive rate. High specificity means that you don't make many false positive classifications. That's what you might want for confirmatory tests, where there's a high cost of *including a false positive*.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I do understand the FPR relation, as I mentioned understanding its relation to FP in the question. My question is about its relation to TN and not TP.